# Why cv2.so missing after opencv installed?

Tags: opencv

Today I installed opencv 2.4.4 to Ubuntu 12.10

But import cv2 not works.

```
root@-:~# python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:53:58) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
>>>
```

As I understand cv2.so missed, so python don't see where opencv

```
root@-:~# find / -name "cv.py"
/root/opencv-2.4.4/modules/python/src2/cv.py
root@-:~# find / -name "cv2.so"
root@-:~#
```

My setup steps look like

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-unix/2.4.4/OpenCV-2.4.4a.tar.bz2
tar -xjf OpenCV-2.4.4a.tar.bz2
cd opencv-2.4.4
mkdir release
cd release 
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE   -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON ..
make && make install
echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf
ldconfig  
echo "PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
echo "export PKG_CONFIG_PATH" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Where is cv2.so ? And why it was missed ?

Comment: Does Cmake correctly detect python on your system? Cmake gives you a pretty long screen output after you call it.

Comment: It should likely be `libcv2.so`, not `cv2.so` (probably located under `/usr/local/lib`)

Comment: Make sure to `sudo apt-get install python-dev`, `sudo apt-get upgrade cmake`, and inspect the `cmake` output manually to make sure the Python library is found (should match `which python`); if not found, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174394/cmake-is-not-able-to-find-python-libraries) for troubleshooting.

Comment: ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so cv2.so

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**How to install opencv(cv2) with python bindings in Linux - Ubuntu/Fedora**

1. Install gcc, g++/gcc-c++, cmake  (apt-get or yum, in case of yum
   use gcc-c++)

   ```
   apt-get install gcc, g++, cmake
   ```
2. Downlaod latest opencv from [openCV's website](https://opencv.org/)
3. Untar it with

   ```
   tar -xvf opencv-*
   ```
4. Inside the untarred folder make a new folder called `release`

   ```
   mkdir release
   cd release
   ```

   (or any folder name) and run this command in it

   ```
   cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
   ```

   the `..` will pull files from the parents folder and will get the system ready for
   installation on your platform.
5. in the release folder run

   ```
   make
   ```
6. After about 2-3 mins of make processing when its finished run

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```
7. Export python path

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
   ```

That's it, now go to python and try

```
>>> import cv2
```

you should not get any error message.

Tested on python 2.7, should be virtually similar to python 3.x.

Comment: Also make sure that the python development headers (sudo apt-get install python-dev) are installed.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Mac OSX, Python 2.7. I don't see errors at any stage but still can't >>>import cv2

Comment: This also didn't work for me on RHEL6, Python 2.7 set up as a virtual environment. I don't see errors at any stage but still can't import cv2. I dont have cv2.so anywhere on my computer after apparently successful installation. @rd108, did you figure out any solution?

Comment: you need to export the Path where Python libraries are installed, like

export PYTHONPATH=~/projects/opencv/release/lib:$PYTHONPATH

Comment: BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON is apparently no longer used.

Comment: I needed to `sudo make install` on the 6th step. Thanks!

Comment: `BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON` is required to build `cv2.so`. Surprisingly.

Answer (score 11):

I install `python-opencv` to solve my problem in Ubuntu 14.04
`sh
sudo apt-get install python-opencv`

Comment: OMG Why didn't anyone say that????? So much easier!

This provided me opencv 2.4.1, Thanks!

Comment: This is indeed a good choice. Users who want the latest versiokn of openCV still need to build the project.

Answer (score 5):

Using raspbian on a rasberry pi I had the problem of the module not being found also. I had three versions of python (2.6, 2.7, and 3.2), be sure you are using python2.7. You can check this by running:

```
python --version
```

I found that for my case it was simply that I needed to install python-dev.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

I did Not have to remove and reinstall opencv, I tried my hardest to avoid that, knowing that it takes a few hours to complete the process.

After installing  python-dev I went to the file I built the opencv into, for me it was " ~/opencv-2.4.9/release", and told it to make

```
sudo make
```

after this I was able to find the cv2.so file. searching for it with:

```
find / -name "cv2.so"
```

at this point I found a few files.
next I ran just the python to see if it could find "import" them

```
python 
>>> import cv2
```

no errors should come up.

```
>>> import numpy
```

I have heard that numpy was necessary for opencv to run. 
From there I believe you should be good to run your script, if no errors come about. I hope this helps.

The page that helped me is listed...

http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/I-can-t-find-cv-so-and-cv2-so-after-compiling-td6671937.html

Comment: Installing `python-dev` and then remaking/reinstalling did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when I manually configured using CMAKE on OSX El Capitan. I had given this additional option:

```
PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH='lib/python2.7/site-packages'
```

which stopped the cv2.so in that package from getting installed. It seems to install properly in my build folder after I removed it:

```
PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE='/usr/bin/python2.7'
PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR='/usr/include/python2.7'
PYTHON2_LIBRARY='/usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib' # TODO - Fix for linux
PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS='/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include' # Todo - Fix for linux


cd $OPENCV_DIR

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$OPENCV_INSTALL_PATH \
                                  -D WITH_CUDA=OFF \
                                  -D BUILD_opencv_python2:BOOL=ON \
                                  -D PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE=$PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE \
                                  -D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=$PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR \
                                  -D PYTHON2_LIBRARY=$PYTHON2_LIBRARY \
                                  -D PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=$PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS \
                                  -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES:BOOL=ON \
                                  ..
make -j8
make install
```

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem in my OS X El Capitan.

I followed the instructions mentioned in [this tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/). Didn't get a successful working install and had the above error of missing cv2.so file in the required folders [mentioned](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/) and at the `python` prompt.

Finally figured that using the virtual python setup was causing trouble. So uninstalled with

```
pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

Then ran

```
brew link opencv
```

which threw errors.

And then followed below steps to resolve the issue.

First run

```
brew link opencv
```

If it gives an error, try for an automated diagnosis

```
brew doctor
```

`brew doctor` gives a list of problems that could be leading to errors in installation process.

To fix problems in case of conflicting files, 
run to get a list of all actions which **will be performed** by overwrite without actually performing them.

To list all files that would be deleted:

```
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run opencv
```

followed by this run which will execute the overwrite, assuming you feel that the actions performed by overwrite will take your system to a more **stable state**.

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:

```
 brew link --overwrite opencv
```

[This tutorial](http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2010/12/14/face-detection-with-osx-and-python/) is a simpler alternative.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me; am in Ubuntu 16.04 on an ec2 instance & had anaconda installed so I just used

`conda install opencv` for both my conda2 and 3 installs

Answer (score 2):

All above answers **did not work for me**, however, after a whole day struggling, I finally solved this problem.

To have cv2.so, we need:

> 1. At least **python 2 or 3** installed. that why people say: `sudo apt-get install python-dev`. But that's **not necessary**, in my case, I use **anaconda python**. (there are many ways to install python)
> 2. **numpy** is also a must. so, whatever python you use, just make sure you have it downloaded. In my case, I use **anaconda numpy**. (anaconda have it installed already, for normal python, use `pip install numpy`)

To tell camke where the path is, just take my command as an example:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
      -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
      -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules \
      -D PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE='/home/parallels/anaconda2/bin/python' \
      -D PYTHON2_LIBRARY='/home/parallels/anaconda2/lib/python2.7' \
      -D PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS='/home/parallels/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include' \
      -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

for python3，you should (I'm using anaconda python, so I linked everything to anaconda):

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
      -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
      -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib-3.3.1/modules \
      -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE='/home/test/SoftWare/anaconda3/bin/python3.6m' \
      -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR='/home/test/SoftWare/anaconda3/include/python3.6m' \
      -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY='/home/test/SoftWare/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.6m.so' \
      -D PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS='/home/test/SoftWare/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include' \
      -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH='/home/test/SoftWare/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages' ..
```

**One thing to remember**!!! before you enter cmake ... **1.** clean your build folder, **2.** **Only camke once!** otherwise you can not change ** PYTHON3_LIBRARY: NO**...(this is a bug I think)

I know there might be some useless arguments, but I am tired to try to clean them. **Here's a screenshot of my cmake print info.**
[screenshot of my cmake info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBJ4Q.png)

You can clearly see that, only python2 can generate cv2.so. python3 can not! (Python3 wrappers can not be generated).

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar problem. After digging into this a little more I came across a post where it was mentioned that `python-numpy` package was required. So, I uninstalled the opencv by running the following command in build folder(in your case release folder):

```
dpkg -r build
```

Then I removed all the opencv files. I installed `python-numpy` and `python-dev` with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy
```

Then, after re-running the installation script, `import cv2` command in python console doesn't give me any error and is properly imported.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a problem with `cmake`:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
sudo apt update
```

If `cmake` is not yet installed:

```
sudo apt install cmake
```

If `cmake` is already installed:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

For more information, see [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610291/how-to-install-cmake-3-2-on-ubuntu-14-04).